# Trigger how to fix these errors

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers

I am trying to make a trigger for every day a movie gets returned late 2$ gets added to the unpaid balance.  The return and due date are in the transaction table, and the unpaid balance is in the members table.  Here is what I have so far, and the errors I am getting any help or suggestions would be great I am really struggling with this one.

```
Create or Replace Trigger Late_Rule
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
For each Row
DECLARE

Fee Number;

BEGIN

Select Date_Due, Date_Returned  
From Transaction;

If new.Date_Returned > new.Date_Due
THEN 
Fee := (new.Date_Returned - new.Date_Due) * 2;


END IF;

Update Member
    Set Unpaid_Bal = Unpaid_Bal + Fee;
end;
/
show error;
```

7/1  PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
10/1  PL/SQL: Statement ignored
10/4  PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.DATE_RETURNED' must be declared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use `:` before `new`. Also i think you don't need `select` sentence:

```
Create or Replace Trigger Late_Rule
BEFORE INSERT ON Transaction
For each Row
DECLARE

Fee Number;

BEGIN


If :new.Date_Returned > :new.Date_Due
THEN 
Fee := (:new.Date_Returned - :new.Date_Due) * 2;


END IF;

Update Member
    Set Unpaid_Bal = Unpaid_Bal + Fee;
end;
```

Let me know if you get any error.

Comment: PLS-00049: bad bind variable 'DATE_RETURNED'    I get that same error for date due as well thats why I thought I needed a select statement

Comment: I had made a mistake. Please check now.

Comment: It works prefect only problem is it updates every single members unpaid balance, so I think its something with my update statement thank you!

Comment: Your `UPDATE` statement has no `WHERE` clause, so of course it will update every row.  You'll have to add some reference to whatever primary key your table has.

Comment: ahh yes thank you I just had to add the where works prefectly now Thank you so much!!